# I have an error updating data, “database is locked” appears, I use Python 3 and sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I rip my code

```
import sqlite3

class Product:

     db_name = 'database_escuela.db'
```

I have the query here

```
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
```

Here I have a function, what I want to achieve is that it goes through the SCHOOL table and updates a field called dias1, but every time it does the error appears

```
def actualizar_estudiantes(self):
    #query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    self.dias1=10
    for row in db_rows:
        print('Entro en Actualizar')
        query = "UPDATE escuela SET dias1 = ?"
        parameters = (self.dias1, )
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        #result.close()
```

I was investigating and I understand that I am opening the table twice, but I do not know how to correct the error, I appreciate the help you can give me, I am starting with python

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
    32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "index5.py", line 183, in actualizar_estudiantes
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
  File "index5.py", line 97, in run_query
    conn.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

new error with modification

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
    32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "index5.py", line 177, in actualizar_estudiantes
     db_rows = self.run_query(query)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'query' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You can just execute the UPDATE SQL once and it will update all the records of escuela table.  The SELECT SQL is not necessary.

Comment: ok but when I remove the Select SQL I get another error, 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'query' referenced before assignment

Comment: Update your code in the question to show how you call the UPDATE SQL.

Comment: I got it like this, put # to skip that call, 
I use that query when adding new data

Comment: Only the four lines in the for loop and `self.dias1 = 10` are enough.

Comment: leaving only the 4 lines this error appears does not recognize db_rows 
l
  File "index5.py", line 179, in actualizar_estudiantes
    for row in db_rows:
NameError: name 'db_rows' is not defined

Comment: You don't need the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, if it worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the UPDATE SQL and it will update all the records of escuela table:

```
def actualizar_estudiantes(self):
    print('Entro en Actualizar')
    self.dias1 = 10
    query = "UPDATE escuela SET dias1 = ?"
    parameters = (self.dias1, )
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if it worked perfectly, thank you